# Can't save proxy settings

Tags: windows-10, proxy

When I click on [my proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPUpF.jpg) in the control panel, while I can toggle the 'use a proxy server' switch, **the change is not saved!** I wish to turn the item off as it causing a huge headache. No browser can connect to the proxy server, because the proxy server doesn't exist! So I wish to turn it off so I can connect to the internet. So I turn the switch off, I click on another menu item, come back and it's still turned on. Nothing I change in the proxy pane (Automatically detect settings, use setup script) is saved! Meanwhile if I go on Airplane mode I can toggle bluetooth (for example) and the change is saved.

The [Registry permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hsT1.jpg) seem to all be in order here. I'm banging my head against a wall. What is going on? Avast says no viruses and yet it seems like something is purposely forcing my proxy settings on.

Comment: @RajeshS There is nothing wrong with the question. Please stop posting comments that are not needed (and are borderline rude).

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting this is the behavior of an infected machine. I ran malware antibytes and it found many malicious registry entites that overrode proxy settings. Why? I don't know.